# How can I print commas between strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

say

```
str(q)=hello
str(w)=332
str(e)=nasa
str(r)=21
```

What should I do in order to print `<hello,332,nasa,21>`?
 Note that brackets and commas are required

Answer (score 3):

Use format:

```
print("<{},{},{},{}>".format(q,w,e,r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string format.

`result = "<%s,%s,%s,%s>" % (q, w, e, r)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39)
>>> q = 'hello'
>>> w = 332
>>> e = 'nasa'
>>> r = 21
>>> print('<{}>'.format(','.join(map(str, [q, w, e, r]))))
<hello,332,nasa,21>
```

This also helps when you have the variables to print already in a list, or a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all elements to a list,which will be a more clear method:

```
myList = ["hello","332","nasa","21"];
myList = ','.join(map(str, myList))
print "<" + myList + ">"
```

As you can iterate over it in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3, you can use the following format:

```
print(f'<{q},{w},{e},{r}>')

<hello,332,nasa,21>
```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQQqxysLIGE&list=PLlrxD0HtieHhS8VzuMCfQD4uJ9yne1mE6&index=11